# Error when running tornado Webserver in terminal

Tags: python, tornado

I am trying to run a tornado webserver in the terminal, but when I run it I simply get a space which is completely empty, and then I have no way of closing the server. Right now I am trying the hello world example.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I have already taken a look at the getting Tornado working question, and the answers there did not solve the issue.

Comment: If it's empty it means it's working fine..
Just go to this [location](http://127.0.0.1:8888 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is type this URL in your browser

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8888
```

But if you do see any error messages

Try changing your port.May be it is being used by other program

```
application.listen(7777)
```

Now point your browser to

```
http://127.0.0.1:7777
```

**Stopping the server**

A simple `ctrl+c` would kill the process.But if you want to do more cleaner way

```
try:
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
```

Comment: could you clarify what you mean when you say "in your browser." I assume you mean something like firefox or google chrome, or am I way off here.

Comment: type that url in your browser(firefox or chrome)

Comment: When I try that I simply get an error that says "This webpage is not available."

Comment: first: run the python script  from terminal  

    `python yourscript.py  `
then  
point that url in your browser

Comment: Thank you SO much @Ajay, that solved it. I only have one question for you. Say I wanted to make it download a file from this website, how would I do that. I am making a conversion server for school and so I would like to have the converted file download from the server.

Comment: http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide.html
Read these docs...
http://tornadogists.com/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212877/when-and-how-to-use-tornado-when-is-it-useless